# Right way to sync git submodules locally

Tags: windows, git, git-submodules

I have a submodule-heavy git structure at my job, and even though I am managing to work with it, it isn't all easy. Well, submodules are evil, after all. But that's what I have to work with, and I'm looking for an easier/righter way.

Imagine a working set with a following structure:

```
root_folder, non-git
├ Project1
| ├ submoduleA
| ├ submoduleB
| └ src
├ Project2
| ├ submoduleA
| └ src
└ Project3
  ├ submoduleA
  └ src
```

I want to make a change in `Project1/submoduleA`, so that it will be visible in `Project2/submoduleA` and `Project3/submoduleA` with the least number of steps.

So far, my itinerary is

0. Make sure all submodules have the same revision and branch I'm working on.
1. Commit my changes in `Project1/submoduleA`.
2. Push them to remote
3. Pull changes from remote `Project2/submoduleA` and `Project3/submoduleA`. The more projects are affected by it, the more bothersome it becomes.

I'd like to find a way that excludes step 2 (pushing to remote).

First, I prefer not to publish unfinished commits, as  may need to amend them if I make typo or simply drafting out the `submoduleA` changes. Second, I may accidentally commit something wrong to remote. Third, dependency on remote may inhibit me from working if there's something with the Internet connection.

I'd like to use symlinks, if it were any unix OS, but I'm on Windows, and I'm not sure if that's a good idea to mix git with symlinks.

I tried googling the solution, but the answer eludes me. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45434038/7643283) was the closest one, I think. But it didn't give me an answer. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1030169/7643283) has a lot of related knowledge, but I don't think it has the bit that I need.

So, does anybody know how to sync git submodules locally, without intermediate push to remote or excessive filesystem juggling?